# Changing background color on a series of tab in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Am working on an application and on the frontend I have some custom tabs which I want when one of them is clicked I capture the text on the tab e.g inpatient and the background color changes after the value is captured.

My goal is I want one tab to be clicked at a time. Basically,
the background color of the currently clicked tab should change 
and the value captured (text on the tab) while the previous clicked tab background color
reverts back to its original state.

Markup code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-11 mx-auto d-flex jbiz-plans">
        <div class="col flex-fill benefit text-center">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Inpatient
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Outpatient
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Dental
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Optical
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Maternity
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript logic I am using

```
let bgColor = false;
$(".benefit").click(function () {
    if (bgColor = !bgColor) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ba0c2f");
        $(this).css("color", "#fff");
        //alert($(this).text());
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#d6d2c5");
        $(this).css("color", "gray");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a codepen or fiddle for the above code?

Comment: Store the reference to the previously changed tab in a variable, so that you can reset the color for that then, when the next one gets clicked …? (What is the `bgColor` variable for in your example btw., are you changing that anywhere outside of the click handler?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your JavaScript to the below. It sets all elements with the class "benefit" to their default background-color and color then changes the element clicked to the new background-color and color:

```
$(".benefit").click(function () {
    // reset old values
    $('.benefit').css("color", "");
    $('.benefit').css("background-color", "");
    // update clicked element
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#d6d2c5");
});
```

Does this achieve what you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/52aL6wzd/

Answer (score 2):

Resetting color of all benefit to default and then setting the value of clicked element should work.

```js
let bgColor = false;
$(".benefit").click(function () {
    $('.benefit').css("background-color", "");
    $('.benefit').css("color", "");
    if (bgColor = !bgColor) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ba0c2f");
        $(this).css("color", "#fff");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#d6d2c5");
        $(this).css("color", "gray");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-11 mx-auto d-flex jbiz-plans">
        <div class="col flex-fill benefit text-center">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Inpatient
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Outpatient
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Dental
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Optical
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 flex-fill benefit text-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/care.png')}}">  <br>
            Maternity
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```